# WPF DataGrid content does not scroll

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

After searching for a fix to this issue in the previous answers I've decided to post my example.
I have the following situation: my datagrid is placed inside a Grid row that is itself placed inside a UserControl.The UserControls does not have a fixed height, as I want the control to resize together with the window. The datagrid is bound to a datasource. Needless to say that the Datagrid itself and its container(the Grid) do not have set a fixed height. My question is: how do I make the vertical scrollbar of the DataGrid to appear?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. My UserControl was placed(at some higher layout level) inside a StackPanel that made the UserControl stretch infinitely vertically.

Comment: Thank you for finding and posting your own answer.  This helped me out today.